# Lucene Incremental Update of Index

Tags: java, mysql, lucene

I'm a bit new to Lucene, I am using a huge database which I indexed previously. The problem is that it is not an efficient way to index the whole table/ database every time if something new is added into it. I'm using lucene3.6.2. I want to make an indexing function which adds the new data to the existing Lucene indexed files, without the need to updateDocument(or delete and re-index in lucene). I mean to say it should not create new files to store the new documents rather should insert them into the previous index files without deleting the previous data inside the index files and without re-indexing the whole database. Whose index should start from the last index location of the previously indexed item, and should be searchable along with the previously generated indexes. This is my indexer code for creating index:

```
public String TestIndex() throws IOException,SQLException
{
     System.out.println("preparing dictionary");
     String output="";
     Long i=0l;
     ResultSet rs = null;
     URL u = this.getClass().getClassLoader(). getResource(SearchConstant.INDEX_DIRECTORY_DICTIONARYDETAILS);
     String dirLoc = u.getPath().replace("%20", " ");
     Directory index = FSDirectory.open(new File(dirLoc));                                                                                //new RAMDirectory();
     StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_30);
     IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_30,analyzer);
     config.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
     IndexWriter w = new IndexWriter(index, config);

     try {
         String SQL = "Select * from test";

         cm = new DbUtility();
         rs = cm.getData(SQL);

         // 1. create the index
         while (rs.next()) {
            Document doc = new Document();

            doc.add(new Field("id",rs.getObject(1).toString() , Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc.add(new Field("Heading",rs.getObject(2).toString() , Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

              w.addDocument(doc);
              i = i + 1;
           }

            System.out.println("I " + i.toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("I in Error " + i.toString());
            System.out.println("Error while retrieving data: "+e.getMessage());
        }

        w.close();
        rs.close();

        return output;
   }
```

Comment: So, you are saying you want to update a document, but you don't want to call `updateDocument`? Am I reading that right?

Comment: @femtoRgon You can also take it as I don't want to delete and then re index the whole data, as its is a time consuming process for a huge database. So can't we make the Indexwriter to write the new data to these previously generated index files keeping previously generated data and not creating new files for storing these new data and not re-indexing the whole database again. Its like opening the previously generated index files, and adding new data inside the files while preserving the previous ones.

Comment: Okay, still not sure exactly what you are trying to solve here. You certainly don't need to recreate the whole database to update one document, just use `updateDocument`. That document, however, does need to be deleted and reindexed (that's what updateDocument does). Exception to that is DocValues fields (see `IndexWriter.updateDocValues`), perhaps that is what you're looking for?

Comment: @femtoRgon sir, it's very simple what I'm trying to say is that if you need to add a new row inside a table, you just insert it. You don't delete the table and then rewrite the whole table, but you just insert that data inside a new row. Similarly when we index this new row of data of a table which was previously indexed, is there any way to add only this data inside the previous index files of this table without the need to reindex the whole table or update(delete and add).

Comment: Why in the world would you think you need to delete the whole index in order to update one document? Just use `updateDocument`.